# Binding two input texts with React

Tags: reactjs, input, bind

I'm learning React and I'm trying to create a program with React that would take texts from two input fields and bind them. I get the input fields but the onClick function is not working. 
Would appreciate if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQOet.jpg)

```
 <div id='root'></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  class CombineText extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {pretext: '', posttext:'', wholetext: '' };
    }

    combineText = () => {
      this.setState({
        wholetext: this.state.pretext + this.state.posttext
      });
    }
    textChanged = (event) => {
      this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.wholetext}</p>
          <input type="text" id="pretext" onChange={this.textChanged} /> 
          <input type="text" id="posttext" onChange={this.textChanged} /> 
          <button onClick={this.combineText}>Press me</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<CombineText />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Comment: Are you receiving any error?

Comment: No, I used the browser debugger and managed to get rid of few bugs I had but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two changes,

**First**: use event.target.id while setting the state on change of input since `name` attribute is not defined on input

**Second**: Specify `button type` to be `button` since its  by default `submit` and `onClick` on the submit button refreshes the page. Or else you could write `event.preventDefault()` in the combineText method to prevent the default submit action behavior

```js
  class CombineText extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {pretext: '', posttext:'', wholetext: '' };
    }

    combineText = () => {
      this.setState({
        wholetext: this.state.pretext + this.state.posttext
      });
    }
    textChanged = (event) => {
      this.setState({[event.target.id]: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.wholetext}</p>
          <input type="text" id="pretext" onChange={this.textChanged} /> 
          <input type="text" id="posttext" onChange={this.textChanged} /> 
          <button type="button" onClick={this.combineText}>Press me</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<CombineText />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Actually, I would have one more question. Why does it have to be event.target.id? Is it because in the render return I am using ids?

Comment: @katjaN, yes, since you are passing the id attribute on the div. If you add a name attribute, you can use event,target.name too. However the attributes need to be available for the element that you are defining it on. If the attribute is not a predefined attribute on element, you need to use `event.target.getAttribute('attributeName')`